# Kinect RGB + Depth to .pcd format

Tags: ros, pcl, rgbd, pcd, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried the rgbd_registration package in which a source cloud (first frame) and a target cloud (another frame) in the form of a .pcd format are passed to the algorithm, the algorithm restores the RGB images from the .pcd file and detects and matches features between the two frames and then aligns the reconstructed 3D points between the two frames.

What I want to do is construct my own .pcd files that will contain depth and rgb images from a Kinect so I can pass it to this algorithm for alignment, instead of using their scenes.

Is there any tutorial or example on how I would be able to store both depth and RGB information into a pcd file?

Thanks for your help

Khalid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57365/kinect-rgb-+-depth-to-.pcd-format/) by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use pointcloud_to_pcd which is part of pcl_ros and should be installed on your system. For instructions on how to use it [look here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros#pointcloud_to_pcd)

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-03-06**:
Thanks for your answer, so does this pointcloud_to_pcd also store the RGB information in the .pcd file? If so, would I be able to change the image that I want saved? (for example rgb/image_rect or image_mono)?

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-03-06**:
It will also store the RGB information but it only works if the pointcloud you are feeding it also contains them. You cannot assign a RGB image to it

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-03-06**:
So does the the pointcloud published by the Kinect contain contain rgb information?

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-03-06**:
if you are using roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch there will be a topic called /camera/depth_registered/points This one contains RGB information

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-03-06**:
I appreciate your help

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-03-06**:
if that solved your issue, please mark the answer as correct by checking it on the left